# Is the Deep Purple song "The Mule" inspired by the character of the same name in Asimov's Foundation series?

Tags: isaac-asimov, inspiration, music, foundation, rock-music

On the album *Fireball* by Deep Purple, there's a song called "The Mule", which opens with the following lines:

> No one sees the things you do
>   Because I stand in front of you
>   But you drive me all the time
>   You put the evil in my mind

In Asimov's *Foundation* series, there's a character called The Mule, who manipulates others using his psychic powers, remaining out of sight himself.

**Is the song based on this character, or are the similarities just coincidence?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the official [Ian Gillan website](http://www.gillan.com/qa-62.html)

> Hello Tamas,
>
> ...
>
> **Yes, The Mule was inspired by Asimov. It's been a while but I'm sure
>   you've made the right connection...Asimov was required reading in the
>   60's.**

Comment: I think The Foundation Trilogy is required reading NOW. Simply tremendous.

Comment: @TonyEnnis There are other trilogies worth while reading like the `Sprawl trilogy` by `William Gibson`, too.